Rotate String in assembly
I am trying to work with strings in assembly so basically:
The input have 3 lines. The first 2 lines have 2 integers and the third line a string.
The first 2 lines have the decryption key. The first is the number of places to rotate the string to the
right. The second is the number to add to each character ASCII code. The third has the string to
decrypt.
And the rotation part is not working correctly:
The iomacros have a macro to get the in and to get a string.
.include "iomacros.inc"

.data
buffer: .space 101  # Reserve 101 bytes for the input string (100 chars + null terminator)
tempBuffer: .space 101 # Temporary buffer for rotation

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    # Read the rotation amount (n) and ASCII shift value (p)
    getint(t0)  # Rotation amount
    getint(t1)  # ASCII shift value

    # Read the string into buffer
    gets(buffer, 100)

    # Calculate the length of the string
    la a1, buffer
    li t2, 0
calculate_length:
    lb a4, 0(a1)
    beq a4, zero, start_rotate
    addi a1, a1, 1
    addi t2, t2, 1
    j calculate_length

la a1, buffer    # Ensure a1 points to the start of buffer

start_rotate:
    # Adjust rotation amount if greater than length
    rem t0, t0, t2  # t0 now contains the effective rotation amount
    li a3, 0        # Reset index for character processing

rotate_loop:
    lb a4, 0(a1)            # Load current character from buffer
    beq a4, zero, end_rotate # Exit loop if null terminator is reached

    add a5, a3, t0           # Add rotation amount to current index
    rem a5, a5, t2           # Correct position if exceeding length
    la a6, tempBuffer        # Start address of tempBuffer
    add a6, a6, a5           # Calculate correct address in tempBuffer

    sb a4, 0(a6)             # Store character in its new position
    
    addi a3, a3, 1           # Increment index for next character
    addi a1, a1, 1           # Move to the next character in the buffer
    j rotate_loop

end_rotate:
    # Copy from tempBuffer back to buffer
    la a1, tempBuffer
    la a2, buffer
    li a3, 0

An input that is not working is:
1
0
HAL
Should print: LHA
But its printing: HAL

Have you tried debugging this?  There's some initialization code that can never run, so that's probably slowing this down.

"la a1, buffer    # Ensure a1 points to the start of buffer" — this line is what we call unreachable code, since it sits in between an jump and the next label; it can never be reached and will never execute.  Have you noticed this during single step debugging?
